# Fetching html between delimiter text and display via js

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I attempted fetching html between two delimiters (here "tools" and "hobbies") via JS, but there is nothing displayed:

```js
fetch('https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Cool_Stuff.html')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const start = data.indexOf('Tools');
    const end = data.indexOf('Hobbies');
    const result = data.substring(start, end); document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
  })
```

I *do have it working in php:

```php
<?php
$url = 'https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Cool_Stuff.html';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$start = strpos($html, '<!------Tools---------->');
$end = strpos($html, '<!-----Hobbies---->', $start);
$length = $end - $start;
$result = substr($html, $start, $length);
echo $result;
?>
```

So:
How can I convince JS to do its job ?

Comment: [Servicable]-<body> <div id="content"></div> <script> fetch("ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Cool_Stuff.html") .then(response => response.text()) .then(data => { const start = data.indexOf("Tools") + 5; const end = data.indexOf("Hobbies") - 7; const content = data.substring(start, end); document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content; }) .catch(error => console.log(error)); </script> </body> </html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling the indexOf parameters for the JS version are different than the ones you using on PHP.

This should do the trick:

```js
fetch('https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Cool_Stuff.html')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    const start = html.indexOf('<!------Tools---------->');
    const end = html.indexOf('<!-----Hobbies---->', start);
    const result = html.substring(start, end);
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: I just realized I'm outputting to "console.log" perhaps we need to change that.

Comment: @Rye: Note that the number of '-' must be correct (I edited the answer to fix this). If you want to match any number of '-', you can use a regex: `const start = html.search(/<!--+Tools--+>/);` (plus means match one or more of the previous pattern, which here is '-'). For `const end = ...`, unfortunately search() doesn't support a second argument for controlling the starting index (unlike indexOf), but in this particular case it doesn't affect the match so you can just drop the "start" argument.

Comment: Regarding console.log: it's useful for debugging (in case you aren't familiar with the Web Developer Tools -- make sure you have the Console open, so you can see the logs and also any error message), but what you originally had with `.innerHTML = result` is also valid (for displaying the result on the page; but note that this should only be done with trusted data).